# Where do I enter cheats, and what do they do?

Tags: saints-row-iv

I joined a co-op game and was notified that I can't earn achievements because my partner was using cheats. What cheats are available and how do I activate them?

Comment: Which platform do you play on? X-Box, PC etc. It will be a great help in order to help you :) Im sure that X-box cheats are different from PC cheats!

Comment: I think cheats can be entered via your (ingame) smartphone; well, in *Saints Row: The Third* at least...

Comment: Is Saints Row 4 out in Asia yet. ME GUSTA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Hub menu > Extras > Cheats to add and enable/disable cheats.

Here's the list of cheats in Saints Row IV:

- Unlock Infinite Sprint - runfast
- Unlock Telekinesis - supertk
- Unlock Stomp - superstomp
- Unlock Blast - superblast
- Unlock Buff - superbuff
- Unlock Death From Above - superdfa
- Disable Super Movement - nosupermove
- Disable Super Powers - nosuperpowers
- Elevator to Heaven (corpses rise into the air) - fryhole
- Give $100,000 - cheese
- Clear Notoriety - goodygoody
- Player Vehicle Smash (any player car will crush other cars like a tank) - isquishyou
- Repair current vehicle - repaircar
- Gives the following weapons (baseball bat, heavy pistol, heavy smg, semi-auto shotgun, automatic rifle, alien rpg and the mcmanus 2020) - letsrock
- Give alien hover vehicle - givehovercar
- Give alien hover tank - givehovertank
- Give alien ufo - giveufo
- Unlock all unlockables - unlockitall
- Fast Forward - fastforward
- Give XOR (alien hoverbike) - givetrouble
- Give Monster Truck - givemonster
- ASCII Mode - ascii
- Disable Warden spawns - nowardens
- Instant Warden Notoriety - instantwarden
- Mascot Peds - mascot
- Pimps and Hos Peds - hohoho
- Insane City - insanecity
- Evil Cars - evilcars
- Disable Glitch FX - noglitchcity
- Big Head Mode - bigheadmode
- Invincible Player Vehicle - vroom

#### Executive Privilege Pack DLC cheats

- Your vehicle has infinite mass and smashes other vehicles out of the way - dlc_car_mass
- You will never die - dlc_never_die
- Unlocks and purchases all Super Power Upgrades - dlc_sosuper
- Maxes out Super Power Strength - dlc_superduper
- Gives you infinite ammo for all weapons - dlc_unlimited_ammo
- You never have to reload because your clip runneth over forever - dlc_unlimited_clip

<sup>Sources:  ["Additional Cheats (SR4 mod)", Saints Row Mods](http://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/additional-cheats.3212/) | ["Cheats in Saints Row IV", Saints Row Wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Cheats_in_Saints_Row_IV)</sup>

---

> I can't earn achievements because my partner was using cheats.

If you're playing the PC version, you'd probably want to install the [**Additional Cheats** mod](http://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/additional-cheats.3212/) (for your SR4 installation and the people you're playing co-op with). Description:

> This mod adds 160 new cheats to the game, as well as changing all cheats to non-flagging... That means using them will no longer disable your autosave or achievements.

Answer (score 4):

As I am unsure what kind of Gaming Platform you are using I will list out both PC and Xbox360/PS3. For XBox360 cheat codes, you can go to [this site](http://gamewise.co/games/46318/Saints-Row-IV/Cheats/Cheat-Codes/Player-Codes)

> To activate cheat mode, pause the game, and select "Extras" and
>   "Cheats". Select "Add Cheat" and enter one of the following codes to
>   activate the corresponding cheat function. If you entered the code
>   correctly, you will hear a sound.

As for the list of Xbox360/PS3 cheats that I currently know of: (I did not add the world codes etc. as you can find these in the website I gave)

> •cheese - gives you $100,000
>
> •letsrock - gives you a full set of weapons
>
> •runfast - you can sprint forever
>
> •whatitmeanstome - give respect
>
> •brains - zombie mode
>
> •ammojocky - toggles unlimited ammo
>
> •vroom - your vehicle is immune to damage

As for the PC version, you can check out [this website](http://www.ign.com/cheats/games/saints-row-4-pc-122148)

> You can enter cheats by accessing the HUB menu, then the Extras menu,
>   and finally the Cheats menu. Entering codes disables auto-saves and
>   also will not allow you to earn any in-game Trophies or Achievements
>   unless you load a save without the cheats enabled. You can enter any
>   cheats below to access the corresponding effects
>
> •cheese - Puts $100k in your pockets (can be spammed multiple times in
>   a row)
>
> •letsrock - Gives you a full load-out of randomized weapons
>
> •goodygoody - Removes the Notoriety from you at any time
>
> •runfast - Your super-sprint doesn't exhaust your Stamina
>
> •fryhole - All of the dead bodies lying around start to raise up into
>   the air
>
> •vroom - Indestructible cars
>
> •isquishyou - All cars can now drive over other cars like tanks (can
>   only be turned off by reloading a clean save)
>
> •hohoho - This makes all of the pedestrians either pimps or
>   prostitutes (LOVE THIS ONE)
>
> •mascot - All pedestrians turn into mascots
>
> •evilcars - Makes all of the cars on the road target you and start
>   attacking you

Comment: The console list looks suspicious. Gang and Police notoriety aren't a thing in Saint's Row IV. Are you sure those aren't Saint's Row 3 codes at all?

Comment: you are right apparently, those codes were incorrect, I searched them up. However, the rest should work